# Why did Charles Ives believe that 'Prizes are badges of mediocrity'?

Tags: award

Source: Liner Booklet of [this CD](https://www.hyperion-records.co.uk/dc.asp?dc=D_CDA67525). The 'Introduction' on that page is the liner booklet.

> The Third Symphony was premiered in 1946 and won the Pulitzer Prize. Ives told the press ‘Prizes are badges of mediocrity’, and hung the citation proudly on his wall.

Comment: Ives was not an establishment figure. Very much the opposite. I guess that on a personal level, he was in conflict between pleasure at recognition, and disgust at acceptance by the establishment which he despised. Hard to prove, but there may be better evidence in available biographies.  The action of dismissing the prize while hanging it proudly on the wall shows some inner contradiction about the whole thing, for sure.